# Propagate exceptions downstream with shared flow similar to `PublishSubject.onError` from RxJava

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

In kotlin `SharedFlow` is a hot observable where we can emit certain values, so I have declared:

```
private val _state: MutableSharedFlow<State> =  MutableSharedFlow()
val state = _state.asSharedFlow()
```

With this in place I can emit states in other places of the class by using `tryEmit(State())`. I'm not sure though what's the right way to achieve emitting error / throwing exception in that hot shared flow. With RxJava it was pretty easy to do with `PublishSubject` and `onError(RuntimeException())` but with shared flow it's different. I couldn't find any relevant API to do that (propagate an error) [link](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow/index.html). The only thing I found is this huge thread and precisely [this comment](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2034#issuecomment-630731259) that gives me a hint:

```
state.map {
    when (it) {
        is Success -> it.value
        is Error -> throw it.exception
    }             
}
```

But this looks more like taking a step back.

Another option is to forget about throwing exceptions and relay on error codes, but for consistency with other parts of my app, I wanted to propagate errors in this flow.

What's the right way of doing that with `SharedFlow` to achieve equivalent of RxJava `onError`?